# Mapping a UserType column of oracle in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a user defined datatype that can contain a list of numbers. How can I map it in Hibernate.

While using the reverse engineer feature of hibernate, I get a Serializable datatype corresponding to this field.

I desire to have some concrete Class for the same.

I explored about org.hibernate.usertype.UserType interface but not sure how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a many to many relation for instance:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "foo_numbers",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fooid") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "numberid") }
    )
    private List<Number> params;

}
```

Of course, you don't need to override all the names in the `@JoinTable` statement.

Comment: Thanks for replying Johan. Could you please elaborate more on this solution.

Comment: This is the opposite to reverse ingeering, with this code you create necessary DB tables (perhaps that's not what you wanted?). This allows some class Foo to have a many-to-many relation with some class Number, which from your description sounded similar to what you asked for.

Comment: I am having a legacy database, its many to many relationship is implemented through a multi-value-column that contains foreign-keys. I doubt if I can use your solution for this.